# how to pass object to PowerShell AddParameter in c#?

Tags: c#, powershell, virtual-machine

I wrote corresponding C# code for the following Powershell command (Works fine on Powershell commandline):

```
Get-VMNetworkAdapter -VM $vm
```

Here is the C# code:

```
PSObject vmFound;
// initizalize vmFound from another PowerShell cdmlet in C#
PowerShell psGetNic = PowerShell.Create();
psGetNic.AddCommand("Get-VMNetworkAdapter");
psGetNic.AddParameter("VM", vmFound);
```

I tried the following as second parameter - nothing works:

```
 psGetNic.AddParameter("VM", vmFound);
 psGetNic.AddParameter("VM", (object)vmFound);
 psGetNic.AddParameter("VM", vmFound.ImmediateBaseObject);
 psGetNic.AddParameter("VM", vmFound.BaseObject);
```

I do not get any return value after running the command `psGetNic.Invoke()`. In other words, how to convert `PSObject` to `object` and pass it as a parameter.

Comment: When you say `nothing works`, is there an error message thrown? if so which?

Comment: no, it returns no result. In other words, nics.Count is 0:Collection<PSObject> nics = psGetNic.Invoke();

Comment: You are passing the argument correctly.  Check the Error stream on psGetNic - that should give you a hint as to what is going wrong.

Comment: Jason, I checked the error stream - but it does not return any result:
errors = psGetNic.Streams.Error.ReadAll(); //errors.Count is 0